# Div containing image will not apply css code

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.image .profile-img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 78%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<div class="profile-card">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="../portrait.jpg" alt="" class="profile-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have literally copied word for word the text in the same text editor. I am not sure what is wrong as browser is showing that .image in css is applying to the div surrounding/ encompassing the image, image has not changed and is still a rectangle

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. Please review it and press the "run code snippet" button to make sure that it demonstrates your problem as you have described it.

Comment: You may also want to use an example image from [Lorem Picsum](https://picsum.photos/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.image .profile-img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 78%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<div class="profile-card">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://static.remove.bg/sample-gallery/graphics/bird-thumbnail.jpg" alt="" class="profile-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.image .profile-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 78%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Just correct your image path and it will work :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).